# I'm having issues installing pyscopg2 on Mac OSX

Tags: psycopg2

ok, so I have researched the other topics on this, but I still can't get this thing to work, and I'm sure its something small I'm overlooking.

I have my python script running on my local host as a web service.

I have my postgresql instance running on my local host with a specific port, and a database created with a table that has data.

All I want to do is utilize psycopg2 to connect to my database from the python script. Should be pretty simple.

Now, as I understand it, I should be able to just download the psycopg2 file, run the setup, and move on from there.

Could someone PLEASE point me in the direction of how to do this? The python setup.py build and/or install command results in permission denied, which is just odd. I ran it with sudo, and again, same thing.

This is the last piece I need to get in place before I can continue working on the application that I was working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using pip?

```
pip search psycopg2
```

if not installed

```
pip install psycopg2
```